# How to get the theme directory URI?

Tags: themes, urls

I want to get the theme root URL with PHP. What would be the best way to do that?

There is a function called `get_theme_root()` which gives me the path but not the URL.

Maybe just get the current themes or parent themes URL and cut the theme directory off? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want [`get_theme_root_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_root_uri). Note that it doesn't contain the trailing slash.

Comment: lol there is a function for that. well i just was ready with `echo dirname ( dirname( get_stylesheet_uri() ) );` ;/